# Container to overlap parent container

Tags: css, html

I have two `divs` inside of eachother. The one **`#outside`** has a `5px border` and the second **`#inside`** has content in it. I want **`#inside`** to overlap **`#outside`** at the top and bottom so that it effectively breaks the border and appears to be 2 brackets, if that makes sense.

**HTML**

```
 <div id='outside'>
      <div id='inside'>
           <h1>Sample header</h1>
           <p>Sample copy</p>
      </div> <!-- inside -->
 </div> <!-- outside -->
```

**CSS**

```
 #outside {
      border: 5px solid #000;
      padding: 5px;
 }
```

I dont quite know how to move the #inside div over the outside div, any advice will help!

Comment: I'm not quite sure what you mean. But if you would like to break the border at the top and bottom you could use `border-left: 5px solid #000; border-right: 5px solid #000`. If that is what you want atleast...

Comment: hi @Mauritz Swanepoel i think u want this http://tinkerbin.com/HfZV7G5f

Comment: This is an expansion of Rohit's answer, but might be a little closer: http://tinkerbin.com/U88cVpby

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Now you can used to `position` for this design

**as like this**

```
#outside {
      border: 5px solid #000;
      padding: 5px;
  position:relative;
 }

#inside{
background:red;
  position:absolute;
  top:-10px;
    left:10px;
  right:10px;
}
```

***[Demo1](http://tinkerbin.com/siCmzU5Y)***

[DEMO2](http://tinkerbin.com/9bzp1zmF)

Comment: Explanation on why this works: 
the position of an element is done according the parent element. If the parent element **outside** does not have a position tag, the **inside** element is positioned related to the **page itslelf**.  So in this case, **inside** is positioned **in an absolute way**, **but relatively to the outside element.**

Answer (score 1):

Add negative margins to inside..

Concept:

```
#inside {
    width:   110%;
    height:  110%;
    margin-top: -10%;
    margin-left: -10%;
}
```

Or make outside `position: relative;` and make inside `position: absolute;` with a `top: -10px; left: -10px;`

Answer (score 1):

http://jsbin.com/enabeb/1/edit

---

```
<div class="outer"> 
    <div class="inner"></div>
  </div>
```

---

```
.outer{
  height:400px;
  width:400px;
  background:#DDD;
  border:8px solid #333;
}
.inner{
  height:416px;
  margin:-8px auto 0 auto;
  width:380px;
  background:#DDD;
}
```

While this is what you asked for, I don't believe it's the best way to do what you're trying to do.

Answer (score 0):

Negative margins don't get processed correctly on my phone (and a couple friends'). position: absolute on the inside div and the appropriate size/padding/border works correctly on desktop, phone, and tablet across every browser I checked it in.